# Nested menu collpapse with Jquery Slidetoggle cascading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have rendered HTML structure that I have no control over which can be seen in the jsFiddle below.

I would like all nodes to be closed at first but expandable via an offset icon so that the original link is preserved as a navigation element.

You will see I am attaching an icon to represent the toggle for any element that has subitems but I am finding my current code is causing all sub lists to also toggle open rather than just the item currently selected:

From the fiddle below if anyone can assist its much appreciated.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='#'>stuff</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>stuff</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href='#'>stuff</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>stuff</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>stuff</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href='#'>stuff</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>stuff</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>stuff</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>stuff</a></li>
</ul>

$('.submenu').hide();

$('.submenu').parents("li").prepend("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></i>");

$('.glyphicon').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('li').find('ul.submenu').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vhew4359/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code a bit.
`$(this).closest('li').find('ul.submenu').slideToggle("fast");` toggles all the `.submenu` infact you want to toggle only the direct `children` or the first one.

```
$('.submenu').hide();

    $('.submenu').parents("li").prepend("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></i>");

    $('.glyphicon').click(function(){
    // here you were toggling all submenu m only toggling the first one 
     $(this).closest('li').find('ul.submenu').first().slideToggle("fast");
    });
```

updated fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/riazxrazor/vhew4359/2/

Answer (score 0):

replace this code `$(this).closest('li').find('ul.submenu').slideToggle("fast");` with `$(this).closest('li').children('ul.submenu').slideToggle("fast");` code